scrapy logger writes to file but does not output to stdout
Logger writes to file but does not output to stdout.
settings.py
LOG_FILE = "otomoto.log"
LOG_FILE_APPEND = True
LOG_ENABLED = True
LOG_SHORT_NAMES = True
LOG_STDOUT = True

main.py
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from otomoto.spiders.passat_spider import PassatSpider
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings


if __name__ == '__main__':
    crawler_setting = get_project_settings()
    configure_logging(crawler_setting)
    crawler_process = CrawlerProcess(settings=crawler_setting)
    crawler_process.crawl(PassatSpider)
    crawler_process.start()

I've tried disabling root logger and everything works. But there are completely different logs from the framework.
Why is there a variable "LOG_STDOUT = True" if it doesn't work with "LOG_FILE = "otomoto.log""?

Do you want to log both to the terminal and the screen?

LOG_STDOUT: If True, all standard output (and error) of your process will be redirected to the log. For example if you print('hello') it will appear in the Scrapy log. Hopefuly this answers the question implied in the title.

I want logs that are written to a file to also be displayed in the console when the spider is running.

You need to configure Python logging for that yourself.

If you want to output the log both to a file and stdout you can add a handler:
import logging


if __name__ == "__main__":
    spider = 'example_spider'
    settings = get_project_settings()
    settings['USER_AGENT'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36'
    settings['LOG_FILE'] = "log.txt"
    logging.getLogger().addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
    process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
    process.crawl(spider)
    process.start()

